# Running a shopping cart application

Tags: shopping-cart, payment, pci-dss, pci-compliance

If I run a shopping cart application, does the web server need to be PCI compliant? The reason I ask because of the fact that I don't process the payments on the site anyway. The main payment method will be through Paypal.

I have not decided yet which shopping cart application that I will use: it could be one of the followings: opencart, magento, zen-cart

Thank you for your input.

Comment: hard to answer. The only question there is "does the web server need to be PCI compliant?". Web server has nothing to do to the PCI ... imho.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## No

Since paypal will be handling credit card data.

see [pci compliance faq](http://www.pcicomplianceguide.org/pcifaqs.php#2)

> Q: To whom does PCI apply?
>
> A: PCI
> applies to ALL organizations or
> merchants, regardless of size or
> number of transactions, that accepts,
> transmits or stores any cardholder
> data. Said another way, if any
> customer of that organization ever
> pays the merchant directly using a
> credit card or debit card, then the
> PCI DSS requirements apply.

Comment: No problem, I didn't even know what pci compliance was before this, but that site is very authoritative. I learned something too!